# Sonata 'entity' type select all value by default

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to select all value in an 'entity' type by default (i've got a multiple choice).

```
$formMapper->add('users', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Custom',
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->join('u.groups', 'g')
                        ->where('g.name = :name')
                        ->setParameter('name', 'custom')
                    ;
                },
                'class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            ));
```

I know that i can use 'data' to set a default value, but how can i select by default more than one value ? (in my case all).

I tryed also to use a closure in 'data'

```
'data' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->join('u.groups', 'g')
                        ->where('g.name = :name')
                        ->setParameter('name', 'custom')
                    ;
                },
```

But I got the following error:

> Unable to transform value for property path "users": Expected a
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.

As suggested i also try to do

```
'data' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    $data = new ArrayCollection();
                    $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->join('u.groups', 'g')
                        ->where('g.name = :name')
                        ->setParameter('name', 'custom')
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult()
                    ;
                    foreach($query as $result) {
                        $data->add($result->getId());
                    }
                    return $data;
                }
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error

> Unable to transform value for property path "users": Expected a
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.

Not sure that this closure is right.

Comment: try to instanciate `ArrayCollection` with the result (which must be an array)

Comment: @smarber i update my question

Comment: I think you should not use a callback but a value, `'data'` value should be `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` object, so try creating a variable  and put the result of doctrine query which you pass as the value of `data`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, it works :)